# Convert PathBuf to String

Tags: rust

I'm trying to convert a PathBuf to a String so it can be inserted into a panic!() message for debugging file not found errors in a CLI program (based on Chapter 12 in the Rust Book).

The current solutions on StackOverflow return `Cow<str>` when using `env::current_dir().unwrap().to_string_lossy()` or `Option<&str>` when using `env::current_dir().unwrap().into_os_string().to_str()`.

These types cannot be fed to a panic!() macro and will throw a compiler error.

Here is the current code:

```
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let cwd = env::current_dir().unwrap().into_os_string().to_str();
    
    if args.len() < 3 {
        panic!("Not enough arguments, give a query argument and a file path. Current working directory is {cwd}");
    }
```

Currently I am trying to use an 'if let' statement with `Option<&str>` to extract the '&str' but the borrow checker blocks me from using it:

```
let pwd: String;
if let Some(str) = cwd {
    let pwd = str.into_string();
}
println!("{pwd}");
```

Comment: What is wrong with the current solutions?

Comment: Their types cannot be fed into a panic! macro. Check & you'll see what I mean. It's not as versatile as println!

Comment: Your attempts don't work, not because of `panic!`, but because you are creating references to values that are immediately dropped before you can print them. The compiler suggests exactly how to fix that issue. See the errors [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=870041b6727aa0698379120c21852df6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way to print a path in a user-facing way is to use [`Path::display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.display):

```rust
let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
let cwd = env::current_dir().unwrap();

if args.len() < 3 {
    let cwd = cwd.display();
    panic!("Not enough arguments, give a query argument and a file path. Current working directory is {cwd}");
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5636b3e3275a45ea4276a600d3d7af53)

Comment: I tried to put everything on one line with 'let cwd = env::current_dir().unwrap().display();' but it doesn't work for some reason, do you know why by any chance?

Comment: That doesn't work because `env::current_dir().unwrap()` returns a `PathBuf`, but `.display()` borrows from it. Rust requires you to store a value before you can borrow from it.